# help! i was updating ubuntu and my computer ran out of battery!

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, updates

I was updating my ubuntu 14.04 to the 16.04 and while it was installing it, my computer ran out of battery. now my computer doesn't run ubuntu properly, I can start the gurb maneger but when I select ubuntu runs like a terminal and then makes me login in an other terminal. what can I do?

Comment: ouch.  This gets messy.  Do you have backups of your personal files?

Comment: After logging in try running `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: Do you know how far in the upgrade it was? In any case, try to reinstall ubuntu-dekstop  with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: it downloaded the ubuntu i think.

Comment: and I don't have any backup =( but i didn't have any important files but i would like to rescue them

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the Ubuntu Desktop with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

If you're able to login normally after that, run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to continue upgrading. Make sure your laptop is plugged-in during the whole upgrade process this time.